# A place to pratice an to try out Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I would like to refresh and improve my knowledge of SharePoint, and also test the creation of Apps on SP 2013 using Access 2013.

I was first thinking about creating an SP environment in a VM, but I realize that the new versions have a lot of requirements, and it would probably be more efficient to find something ready for use.

SO my question is: where do I find such a place ? Specialised hosting companies ? I had a quick look at MS Azure, but it seems that setting up VM's for this has a prohibitive cost for a freelance like me, who just wants a practice place -and eventually a showcase place.

I already saw [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/75239/19022) which is really interesting, but I thing version 2013 is much more complex to setup !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.cloudshare.com they have a SharePoint Server 2013 RTM and Project Server 2013 RTM pre configured virtual machine.  They also offer free trials too.

Answer (score 1):

Access services is not available with SharePoint online. If you are looking to work with other aspects of SharePoint besides Access Services, perhaps start with a free trial of Office 365. Or spring for a [paid plan](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-products-and-free-trial-online-collaboration-tools-FX103789417.aspx) at $3 per month per user.

Otherwise, you're right. Getting your own instance seems to be expensive.

Comment: THanks! This page (http://goo.gl/i2IypP) seems to indicate that Access Services are indeed part of the Plan 1.

Comment: Users beware.  If you sign up for SP online, it's for a year! I just got trapped 8-( And th eminimum price gives you 0 GB storage. And I guessed that if you wnt to try out anything serious, you need at least 2 accounts.
And prepare to switch browser, since some parts simply do not seem to work in Chrome.